# Synthesis of Blocking Statements in Verilog - time required for circuit to complete

Tags: verilog, timing

This question is purely about synthesized verliog, not simulated.

I have read that blocking assignments are executed in order, but also that blocking assignments assign values to the RHS **immediately**.  These two seem to contradict each other.

Eg. take a for loop adder:

```
reg signed [15:0] signalHist [127:0];
integer i;
reg signed [142:0] sum = 0;
wire triggerSum = 0;
...

always @ (posedge clk) begin
if (triggerSum==1) begin
    sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<128; i=i+1) begin
        sum = sum + signalHist[i];
    end
end
```

In this example's case, how can the value for sum be assigned to its register **immediately**?  What happens if we are summing 1000 or 100000 int16s?

Or, does the word **immediately** as I used above just mean "after the required amount of processing time"?

If the number of integers being summed gets to be very large (or more generally, if we have too many blocking statements each which depends on the previous), could it be possible that the synthesized circuit would take more than a clock cycle to evaluate?

**EDIT:**

Below is a simplified version of the code Im trying to run. Its basically a FIR filter.  I stripped out the ADC/DAC interfacing sections so that this code:

- Loads data from INDATA[7:0] every 1000 clock cycles (inDataCounter flips every 500 clock cycles)
- On next clock cycle, shifts the array signalHist[] by 1 and puts the new INDATA into the first index
- On next clock cycle, multiplies signalHist[] .*  taps[] (point by point) and saves the result in product[]
- On the next clock cycle, sums all of product[] into sumSum
- On the next clock cycle, sets part of the resulting sumSum to OUTDATA (output pins)

```
    always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        //Simulate new data clock, every 1000 cycles
        if (inDataCounter < 500) begin
            inDataCounter <= inDataCounter+1;
        end else if (inDataCounter == 500) begin
            inDataCounter <= 0;
            inDataClk<= ~inDataClk;
            
            // Filter taps, hard coded for now, update-able here
            taps[0] <= 271;
            taps[1] <= -961;
            taps[2] <= 2574;
            ...
            taps[2047] <= 15;
        end


        triggerSampleAddLast <= triggerSampleAdd;
        if (triggerSampleAddLast != triggerSampleAdd) begin
            //shift the time array and add the new element
            for (jj=2047; jj>0; jj=jj-1) begin
                signalHist[jj] <= signalHist[jj-1];
            end
            signalHist[0] <= adcSample[17:2];
            signalHistTrig <= ~signalHistTrig;
        end
        
        
        signalHistTrigLast <= signalHistTrig;
        if (signalHistTrigLast != signalHistTrig) begin
            for (kk=0; kk<2048; kk=kk+1) begin
                product[kk] <= taps[kk]*signalHist[kk];
            end
            productTrig <= ~productTrig;
        end
        
        productTrigLast <= productTrig;
        if (productTrigLast != productTrig) begin
            sumSum = 0;
            for (ll=0; ll<2048; ll=ll+1) begin //4096 or 256 loops
                    sumSum = sumSum + product[ll];
            end
            doneReading = ~doneReading;
        end

        doneReadingLast <= doneReading;
        if (doneReadingLast != doneReading) begin
            OUTDATA[15:0] <= sumSum[35:20];//signalHist[0];//sumSum[18:3]; //sumSum[18:3];//adc0_sample[17:2];//;//output dac spi word  
        end
    end
```

And below, the new data sample coming in

```
    always @ (posedge inDataClk) begin
        adcSample <= INDATA;
        triggerSampleAdd<=~triggerSampleAdd;
    end
```

This takes 269k logic blocks to complete, 1000+% of my FPGA.
Is there any way to reduce the number of logic blocks required, by splitting up into multiple cycles?

Is there a better way to split up things onto multiple cycles?

Comment: Is this code synthesizable? The semantics of the word "immediately" changes depending if the code is running on a simulation or if it is being synthesized. I'm not with synthesizer here to check if your code synthesizes, that's why I've asked if it synthesizes. Anyway, if it does, I strongly recommend you to check the RTL synthesis output and check if indeed does what was intended

Comment: Probably your code is going to generate a large adder tree in order to implement the for loop before registering on the flip flop, thus satisfying the "immediately"

Comment: It synthesizes when I have only a small number of loops; but when I have many loops the synthesis tool spins for a long time (I have stopped it after 30-60mins).

Comment: Can you post the entire code? It is taking too long probably because the adder tree is so big that it is failing to route the signals. In many cases, when there is a for loop in verilog, it is synthesized as a combinational circuit that gets registered only at the last level

Comment: I let Quartus run for a while and it finally did synthesize, but it requires too many logic elements for my chip.  It requires 200k logic elements, and I have ~20k.  Is there a way to make it require fewer logic elements, perhaps pipelining or splitting it into steps?

Comment: I believe it is possible to design a simpler architecture for your circuit, but first we need to understand what are you trying to achieve. Could you provide some drawings (schematics) of the circuit you're trying to describe?

Comment: @HadleySiqueira I have added my verilog code to the original post.  It requires 200k logic elements, but I wonder if there is a better way to split it up into multiple clock cycles that would require fewer clock cycles.  Thanks.

Comment: Please understand that HDL is not *"code"* that *"runs"*. There is no *"processing time"* as in software. This **describes** a hardware and the synthesis tool tries to translate the HDL into the hardware it supports. Before there were 128 chained adders, consequentially with a considerable delay (if even practical). After the edit, there are now 2048 multipliers and 2048 chained adders!

Comment: The 2048 multipliers should be able to operate in parallel, as each is independent from the others, correct?  Or is this incorrect?

Comment: Is there a better way to perform this math on an FPGA - ie splitting into multiple clock cycles?  Would that reduce the logic elements required?

Comment: Yes, it would reduce the LEs required. My advice for you is: try to draw the circuit you're trying to describe and check for your bandwidth requirements. You said that new data only arrives after 1000 thousand cycles. Ask yourself: do you really need to do all operations in parallel in one clock cycle when data only arrives in intervals of 1000 cycles?

Comment: @HadleySiqueira thanks, I have done more experimenting and it seems to me that the large #logical elements used is simply because of the large array, or routing the array to where it needs to go.  I did split it up into 500 or so cycles (reusing the same multiplier each time) and it still uses many elements (though less).  I'm going to try using built in memory to see if it helps.  And yes, I do want it as fast as possible as it is a realtime application where tenths of microseconds matter.  I am trying to assess what is physically possible right now.  Thanks

Comment: Even if your application is real time there must be requirements. For instance, how many samples per second should your circuit evaluate? Probably you're using a 50MHz clock and you said that every 1000 cycles a new input is generated. If this is true, it means a new data arrives every 20us. 20us (or 1000 cycles) should be enough to process your filter with a proper architecture (that probably uses fewer logical elements)

Comment: Just a simple estimate: you need to perform 2048 multiplications then 2048 sums, a total of 4096 operations that must occur every 1000 cycles. So you need to be able to do 4096/1000 = 4,096 operations per cycle. Lets round up to five operations. With five adders and five multipliers working in parallel and pipelined would get you near where you need. Let's double that to 10 multipliers and 10 adders. This is a total of 20 processing elements. Your verilog code is trying to generate 4096 processing elements. 4096 elements vs 20 elements is a huge difference

Comment: When using for loops in verilog for synthesis, I like to think about then as copy and paste operations. When synthesizing, the tool is trying to place the circuit in the FPGA, route it etc. When you do a for loop, you're saying to the synthesis step: please place 2048 adders and 2048 multipliers. See that this is totally different from a software for loop.

Comment: I don't know how much you know verilog. If you're new on the language, I suggest you to read a book named "FPGA prototyping by verilog examples". Many books about HDL languages try to teach HDL languages as they were software programming languages (maybe in hope to use known elements to programmers?). The book I'm suggesting teachs the languague in the right way (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

The context of blocking assignments being updated immediately applies only to simulation.

For a synthesis flow (targeting physical resources is an FPGA or ASIC) blocking assignments model combinational logic which has propagation delay.  The propagation delay depends heavily on the logic being modeled, on the technology that the synthesis, the place & route tools are performing the technology mapping, and the physical targeted device itself.

In general, the combinational logic propagation delays are not known at simulation time, a model known as the stratified event scheduler is used for simulation and behaves such that combinational and sequential logic is reliably modeled to behave like hardware without knowing the delays.

It works but its still only a simulation model.

Synthesis and place & route tools provide reports on the physical delays.  More specifically the static timing analysis tool provides an analysis of each path in the design post synthesis and post place & route.

Answer (score 1):

Every operation with in an "always @ (posedge clk)" block has to happen within the same clock cycle, and therefore gets synthesized into separate hardware. So in the case of this code:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (triggerSum==1) begin
        sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<128; i=i+1) begin
        sum = sum + signalHist[i];
    end
end
```

That synthesizes into a chain of 128 separate adders. This is why you have no space left.

In order to make this work, you will have to pull the loop out of the always block and turn it into a clock+counter combination. Instead of trying to use 128 adders in one clock cycle, use one adder over and over for 128 clock cycles.

Looking at your longer code, trying to do 2048 operations over 1000 clock cycles will be a problem, so you'll need to have something like

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   if(accumulatorRunning==1) begin
      sum <= signalHist[count]*tap[count] + signalHist[count+1]*tap[count+1] + signalHist[count+2]*tap[count+2] signalHist[count+3]*tap[count+3];
      count <= count + 4;
   else
      sum <= 0;
      count <= 0;
   end
   resultReady <= (count == 2048 - 4);
end
```

For learning this style, you may find it useful to try writing some SIMD assembler. That way you can quickly iterate, use a debugger, etc.